# How do I shutdown/close a process?

Tags: c#, winforms

In the top of a class I did:

```
Process[] pname = Process.GetProcessesByName("BFBC2Game");
```

Then I'm doing a check:

```
if (sensor.Value >= (float)numericupdown)
{
}
```

For example, if the temperature of the video card is over 120c then shut down/close the process `BFBC2Game`; just shut down the game right away.

Comment: `foreach (Process p in pname) p.Kill();`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could loop through all the processes, and kill each one:

```
pname.ToList().ForEach(p => p.Kill());
```

> [Process.Kill](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.kill%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): Stops the associated process immediately.

Answer (score 4):

Just bear in mind kill is a hard kill, you should always try and shut it down cleanly first. Kill can leave undesired effects. Try Close() first IMO http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.close(v=vs.110).aspx